# Change xml node value

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml like mentioned below:

```
<Attributes>
  <Attribute>
    <EntryID>0</EntryID>
    <ContractID>227860</ContractID>
    <FieldID>10882</FieldID>
    <GroupID>0</GroupID>
    <InstanceID>0</InstanceID>
    <Value>C:\Users\laitkor\Downloads\BulkTest826.mp4</Value>
    <CreatedBy>615</CreatedBy>
    <CreatedOn>12/1/2014 6:51:04 AM</CreatedOn>
    <UpdatedBy>615</UpdatedBy>
    <UpdatedOn>12/1/2014 6:51:04 AM</UpdatedOn>
  </Attribute>
</Attributes>
```

I have to change the node value 'Value' from `C:\Users\laitkor\Downloads\BulkTest826.mp4` to `BulkTest826.mp4`.

I have tried changing the value by using:

```
  XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.LoadXml(nodes); 
        bool isMultimedia = false;
        XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/Attributes/Attribute");
        foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
            {
            int FieldId = Convert.ToInt32(xn["FieldID"].InnerText);
            isMultimedia = true;
            if (isMultimedia) {
            string MultiMediaFilePath = xn["Value"].InnerText;
            createMultimediaFile(FieldId, MultiMediaFilePath, contractID);//todo
            string fileName = MultiMediaFilePath.Substring(MultiMediaFilePath.LastIndexOf('\\', MultiMediaFilePath.Length - 1));
            fileName = fileName.TrimStart('\\');
            xn.SelectSingleNode("/Attributes/Attribute/Value").InnerText = fileName;

                }
            retval = SiteProvider.ContractBulk.AddBulkContractField(nodes, contractID, groupID, sequenId, 1);//issue here
            return retval;
            }
```

But the value of nodes I am getting in XML format does not have the updated Value for 'Value' node at line mentioned with comment 'issue here'

Comment: Check my solution and tell me if this is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.LoadXml(nodes);
        bool isMultimedia = false;
        XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/Attributes/Attribute");

        foreach(XmlNode node in xnList)
        {
            XmlNode n1 = node.SelectSingleNode("Value");

            //I will suppose that you need to do that for more than one Value node
            if(n1.InnerText.Contains(@"C:\Users\laitkor\Downloads\"))
            {
                n1.InnerText = n1.InnerText.Replace(@"C:\Users\laitkor\Downloads\", "");
            }
        }
```

I'm supposing that you want to this more than once for different files. I used to replace the `C:\Users\laitkor\Downloads\`, if the location can be different you can find index of last `\` and `substring` till this index.

Comment: sorry..but this also didn't work.The XML(nodes) i got at second last line('//issue here') is same and value is not updated.

Comment: @ajitasrivastava with this line you are changing the value, if the issue here line doesn't work probably you should look into method which is not working. You can debug it and see that this code change the xml node value. Check AddBulkContractField method.

Answer (score 0):

Use XElement from System.Linq.Xml namespace. Much more intuitive XML parsing.

```
var xml=
XElement.Parse(yourXml); // or load XElement.Load(file);
var node = xml.Descendants()
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Value" && x.Parent.Name =="Attribute"); 

node.Value="BulkTest826.mp4"; // If you only need one
// Or
var valueNodes = xml.Descendants("Value");
foreach(var val in valueNodes)
{
  // val.Value = "You new value";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
        XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("Attributes/Attribute");

        foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
        {
            node.SelectSingleNode("Value").InnerText = fileName;
        }
```

Problem is that you are trying to get from node /Attributes/Attribute node /Attributes/Attribute/Value

Comment: @ajitasrivastava have you save xml document? Like this doc.Save().

Comment: @ajitasrivastava also you are put to SiteProvider.ContractBulk.AddBulkContractField nodes as parameter. In your code it's just a string. Try like this: SiteProvider.ContractBulk.AddBulkContractField(doc.InnerText, contractID, groupID, sequenId, 1);

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;                 
using System.IO;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        //XElement xml = XElement.Load(xmlFile); //Load from file
        XElement xml=XElement.Parse(@"<Attributes>  <Attribute>    <EntryID>0</EntryID>    <ContractID>227860</ContractID>    <FieldID>10882</FieldID>    <GroupID>0</GroupID>    <InstanceID>0</InstanceID>    <Value>C:\Users\laitkor\Downloads\BulkTest826.mp4</Value>    <CreatedBy>615</CreatedBy>    <CreatedOn>12/1/2014 6:51:04 AM</CreatedOn>    <UpdatedBy>615</UpdatedBy>    <UpdatedOn>12/1/2014 6:51:04 AM</UpdatedOn>  </Attribute></Attributes>");
        var valueElements = xml.XPathSelectElements("//Attribute/Value");

        foreach(XElement valueElement in valueElements)
        {           
            valueElement.Value=Path.GetFileName(valueElement.Value);
            Console.WriteLine(valueElement.Value);
        }
    }
}
```