# c# Form Project won't save Setting changes of Console Project

Tags: c#, forms, configuration, console

## Background

#### Console Application:

I have a console application that retrieves data from a spreadsheet using the google sheets API. This application is automated by running it every 5 minutes with windows scheduler.

#### Form Application:

In the same solution I have created a windows form project that can be run manually, outside of the automation process to tweak any settings without disturbing the 5 minute process.
 (i.e. If we want to change spreadsheet ID to fetch data form a different spreadsheet, or if i want to change the output folder of where the data is being fetched)

---

### My Goal

I'm trying to develop a form project that will edit the "settings.settings" file of another project in the same solution. Below is a screenshot of how i have my solution laied out:

[image: Solution/Project Layout]

---

### What I've done so far

I've already added a reference from my sheetstocsv project in my SettingsUI Project, and i've successfully created a form that accesses sheetstocsv's Settings and edits them when a save button is clicked. Shown below is the function that's supposed to save the new settings from the form.

```
private void Save_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sheetstocsv.Properties.Settings.Default.outputdir = OutputDirectory_TextBox.Text;
    sheetstocsv.Properties.Settings.Default.spreadsheetID = SpreadsheetID_Textbox.Text;
    sheetstocsv.Properties.Settings.Default.Entity = Entity_Texbox.Text;
    sheetstocsv.Properties.Settings.Default.headernum = (int)Columns_NumericUpDown.Value;
    string headers = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)Columns_NumericUpDown.Value; i++)
    {
        headers = headers + Columns_DataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[i].Value.ToString() + ",";
    }
    sheetstocsv.Properties.Settings.Default.headers = headers;
    sheetstocsv.Properties.Settings.Default.configured = true;
    sheetstocsv.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    MessageBox.Show("Saving Complete!", "Settings", 
    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
}
```

---

### How I'm trying to do it

Below is a code snippet of how i'm only letting the sheetstocsv project continue if the configuration file has configured it first

```
 //Check for if configured
 if (Properties.Settings.Default.configured == false)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Program has not been configured yet! Please Run SettingsUI first to start this program.");
     Console.ReadLine();
     Environment.Exit(0);
 }
```

---

### My Problem

Whenever I run my settingsUI, save, and then run my sheetstocsv project the changes that were supposed to be saved are not. and it will not allow the program move foward.

---

## Edit

Below is the full form .cs that shows how i'm editing the properties of the other project

```
using sheetstocsv;
namespace SettingsUI
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Columns_DataGridView.RowCount = 1;
            Columns_DataGridView.ColumnCount =(int)Columns_NumericUpDown.Value;
        }

        // Event handlers for other UI elemets here.......

        private void Save_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sheetstocsv.Properties.Settings.Default.outputdir = OutputDirectory_TextBox.Text;
            sheetstocsv.Properties.Settings.Default.spreadsheetID = SpreadsheetID_Textbox.Text;
            sheetstocsv.Properties.Settings.Default.Entity = Entity_Texbox.Text;
            sheetstocsv.Properties.Settings.Default.headernum = (int)Columns_NumericUpDown.Value;
            string headers = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < (int)Columns_NumericUpDown.Value; i++)
            {
                headers = headers +     Columns_DataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[i].Value.ToString() + ",";
            }
            sheetstocsv.Properties.Settings.Default.headers = headers;
            sheetstocsv.Properties.Settings.Default.configured = true;
            sheetstocsv.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

            MessageBox.Show("Saving Complete!", "Settings", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please don't post screenshots of code. Add them to the question as you have under "how i'm trying to do it"

Comment: Your console application is the startup project. Can you please show: 1. how you are launching the SettingsUI form and 2. How `sheetstocsv` (referenced in your `Click` event) is instantiated.

Comment: You won't be able to access the other application's settings by default, because of how the Settings class works. You'd have to go find the settings file in the %AppData% folder and adjust them there. Or, configure the settings in an App.Config and load it from there (that's what I'd suggest).

Comment: @RufusL I went ahead and fixed the code and removed the picture, Also i have provided a more complete version of my form file.

Comment: @RufusL The console project is seperate from the from project. one does not get launched from the other, but the form project should be able to edit the console project's settings.

Comment: This is all very much by design, one program should never accidentally change the settings of another program.  You'll have to wrangle ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration().  But surely most any user will favor a Options menu entry instead of being slapped across the face with an obscure hint displayed in a message box.

Comment: @RufusL I have added more information please let me know if this helps clarify my problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite have enough info from your question (see comment from Rufus), but I am guessing that your console app launches your WinForm? If this is the case, what is likely happening is this:

1) Console app starts, and loads the config file into memory.
2) Your Winform launches and changes the config file.
3) Console app overwrites the changes to the config file on exit since it read it before the changes were made.

You could just move the winform into your console project, then just do something like this:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.outputdir = OutputDirectory_TextBox.Text;
...
```

Adding More Info (Oct 1):

I must be honest, doing what you're doing is a little strange, and I would really rethink referencing an executable to change its default settings. Just because VS lets you do this, doesn't necessarily mean you should. But if you must, there are a couple other things you can try:

1) You can simply parse the xml settings file and change node values of the settings you want to change. System.Xml namespace will make very short work of this. The post below has good examples:

[Change xml node value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27226124/change-xml-node-value)

2) Try wrapping the code that is currently in your button click event handler with some method inside the console project. This way, you're calling a method that changes the settings, rather than trying to change the settings from an external assembly.

Note: neither of those methods will work if your console app is running while you're making changes to its config file. On shut down, the console app will overwrite the settings file with the settings it loaded into memory when it started up. If the console app isn't running, 1) will definitely work.

Comment: The console project is seperate from the from project. one does not get launched from the other, but the form project should be able to edit the console project's settings.